# run external application in linux using qprocess

Tags: linux, qt, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am creating an GUI application using QT creater in Raspbian. When I click a button I want to open an external application like terminal, or browser, etc.

I have tried many attempts

- attempt 1

```cpp
std::system("/usr/share/raspi-ui-overrides/applications/scratch.desktop&");
```

it says me permission denied

- attempt 2

```cpp
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("/usr/share/raspi-ui-overrides/applications/scratch.desktop"));
```

- this one is working but its not opening the application but its opening in terminal:

```cpp
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("/usr/share/raspi-ui-overrides/applications/scratch.desktop"));
```

Comment: show the content of `scratch.desktop`

Comment: Are you able to execute `/usr/share/raspi-ui-overrides/applications/scratch.desktop&` from a terminal?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the question is about Raspberry Pi and Raspbian.

In Raspbian, the `scratch.desktop` and other `*.desktop` files are not executables, but just text files that describe which application to run.

Example:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /usr/share/raspi-ui-overrides/applications/scratch.desktop 
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
TryExec=scratch
Exec=scratch
Icon=scratch
Terminal=false
Name=Scratch
Comment= Programming system and content development tool
Categories=Application;Development;
MimeType=application/x-scratch-project
```

You need to use an actual binary to start the process. For `scratch`, it would be `/usr/bin/scratch`. For a browser, it's likely to be `/usr/bin/epiphany-browser`. Look at `Exec=` line in the `*.desktop` file to see the name of the executable, then use `which` in the terminal to see its location:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ which epiphany-browser 
/usr/bin/epiphany-browser
```

Comment: Hi I have tried using this path /usr/bin/scratch still the application is not opening

Comment: Does it work if you run `/usr/bin/scratch` in the terminal?

Comment: Also, it's not `QDesktopServices::openUrl`, it's more likely `QProcess::execute` as @eyllanesc suggests.

Comment: @MohdViquar use `QProcess::startDetached("/usr/bin/scratch");`

Comment: hi yes its working when I use /usr/bin/scratch on qprocess::execute command how to find the location of other application? thanks

Comment: @MohdViquar Typically in Linux the executables are in the folders `/usr/bin` or `/bin`

Comment: thanks alot mate I have find the way to do it thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

The .desktop files are not executable, but serve as shortcuts for the desktop system. Assuming that the scratch.desktop has the following:

scratch.desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Scratch
Comment= Programming system and content development tool
Exec=scratch
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=scratch
Categories=Development;
MimeType=application/x-scratch-project
```

Then the executable is `/usr/bin/scratch`, And you can run it with Qt:

```cpp
QProcess::startDetached("/usr/bin/scratch");
```

Or:

```cpp
QProcess::execute("/usr/bin/scratch");
```